# Getting exception "No serializer found for class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct" while sending message to kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jackson, spring-kafka

Our code to serialize a POJO and send it as json to kafka is failing with the exception below.

Code:

```
@lombok.Data
public class EventsDTO {
    private Struct dataAfterWrite;
    private String operation;
}

...

public void sendMessage(EventsDTO data) {
    Message<EventsDTO> message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(data)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "events-ingestion-topic")
            .build();
    kafkaTemplate.send(message);
    log.info("message send to kafka topic {}", message);
}
```

application.properties has

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Here's the exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data [EventsDTO(dataAfterWrite=Struct{id=61713742,...,event_state=0}, operation=c)] for topic [events-ingestion-topic]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer.serialize(JsonSerializer.java:216)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer.serialize(JsonSerializer.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1005)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:952)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:752)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.observeSend(KafkaTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:546)
    at com.events.debeziumconnectorservice.kafka.KafkaProducer.sendMessage(KafkaProducer.java:25)
    at com.events.debeziumconnectorservice.debezium.Listener.handleChangeEvent(Listener.java:62)
    at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder.lambda$notifying$0(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:75)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine$1.handleBatch(EmbeddedEngine.java:518)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:913)
    at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder$2.run(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.events.debeziumconnectorservice.models.EventsDTO["dataAfterWrite"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1306)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:408)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:53)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1572)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1273)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectWriter.java:1163)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer.serialize(JsonSerializer.java:213)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Update:

Changing

```
public class EventsDTO {
    private Struct dataAfterWrite;
    private String operation;
}
```

to

```
@Data
@JsonInclude
public class EventsDTO {
    public Struct dataAfterWrite;
    public String operation;
}
```

didn't help. Got same exception.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you please share your application configuration? (particularly the spring.kafka.properties)

Comment: spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you've defined a field `private Struct dataAfterWrite`, and Jackson doesn't know what to do with it.

Perhaps you wanted a different type there?

Comment: I changed private Struct dataAfterWrite to public. Still same error.

Comment: The problem is `Struct` not the access level. That class is not JSON compatible. Meanwhile, a `TreeMap<String, Object>` or `JsonNode` is

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the Struct from the EventsDTO POJO. The Struct class is not serializable as it has no public fields:

```
public class Struct {

    private final Schema schema;
    private final Object[] values;

   ...

}

public class EventsDTO {
    private String operation;
}
```

Now, the exception doesn't occur.

Comment: Ideally, you dont define your own Struct class in case you mistakenly import the Kafka Connect class instead, but public fields don't matter for Jackson